# How does jquery partial selectors work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My page render comments like this:

```
<div class="ReadComment comment#1">
    First comment
    <br>
    <span>posted by vi vi on 2/25/2013</span>
    <p>My first comment</p>
</div>
```

Where I enumerate sequence order of my comments with 'comment#' class.

I tried to use jquery selector to select all element which classes start with 'comment#':

> var comments = $("div[class^='comment#']");

But it does not work this way.
Instead

> ```
> var comments = $("div[class*='comment#']");
> ```

works perfectly fine.

I thought that jquery checks each element's class individually. So if I write `[class^='comment#']` it will check  `ReadComment`class first and then `comment#` class.

But it seems that it check just row of the classes.
Is it so?
Could some one explain how does it work? I failed at searching for explanation) 
Thank you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are attribute selectors. In your case, you check to see if the `class` attribute literally starts with the string `comment#`, which it doesn't (I don't think `#` is a valid character for class names either).

`*=` works because it checks to see if `comment#` is within the attribute's value, which it is.

If you want to do more advanced filtering, you'll have to use `.filter()` and write a function yourself.

Comment: thank you for such detailed answer) not I understand my mistake)

Comment: Here is the source that is showing this: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L1027

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery `#` is reserved for DOM `id` selection.

`comment#` What this code does is looking for comment tag whth `id`.

That is incorrect and `$("div[class*='comment#']")` this select DOM with class contain `comment#` means find class that contain `comment#` at end or beginnig or any where in class name.